pecl install xdebug on MacOS fails with error 'asm goto' constructs are not supported yet
MacOS Ventura 13.6.6
I installed php version 8.1 using homebrew. Immeidately after I did
pecl install xdebug

I get the following error:
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c:21:
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src/lib/php-header.h:19:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.27_1/include/php/main/php.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.27_1/include/php/Zend/zend.h:409:
/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.27_1/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:490:10: error: 'asm goto' constructs are not supported yet
        __asm__ goto(
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.27_1/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:553:10: error: 'asm goto' constructs are not supported yet
        __asm__ goto(
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.27_1/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:623:10: error: 'asm goto' constructs are not supported yet
        __asm__ goto(
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.27_1/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:733:10: error: 'asm goto' constructs are not supported yet
        __asm__ goto(
                ^
4 errors generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

This is very similar to this question, which points to this bug report which says that I have to use the same compiler for both PHP and Xdebug. OK, I get the concept, but are there any details on how to achieve this? I don't know my way around C compilers on the Mac (or anywhere, really). How can I make brew and pecl use the same compiler?
For info:
$ pecl -V
PEAR Version: 1.10.14
PHP Version: 8.1.27
Zend Engine Version: 4.1.27
Running on: Darwin OLFs-iMac.local 22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Mon Feb 19 19:48:53 PST 2024; root:xnu-8796.141.3.704.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

I tried compiling PHP from source thinking that would somehow work, but Xdebug expects PHP to be installed via Homebrew, so that didn't work.
I updated my MacOS to Ventura thinking I needed newer XCode stuff, although Apple still doesn't allow me to download the latest Xcode. So I downloaded and installed "CLI tools for XCode 14.3.1" from the Apple developer site.
Each time I made sure to brew uninstall php and checked that php and pecl were removed from my system before trying to install both again back to back.
I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Disable asm goto operators by setting # define ZEND_USE_ASM_ARITHMETIC 0 in /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/Zend/zend_operators.h:508
Note: Replace 7.4.11 with your version PHP
